# Is it possible to use Kotlin files and Java files in the same project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, xampp, mapbox

I'm building a navigation app, like Google Maps and I'm using Mapbox for integrating the maps. For map integration and all of that, I've used Kotlin files. However, I'm trying to add a login and register screen (for users to save their favourite routes), and I want to use XAMPP for that.

I want to know if I can use Java files (in the same project) for this part because I find it easier to work with Java at this point. And also, if I run the project, if both Kotlin and Java files can work properly together.

Comment: Kotlin is fully interoperable with Java so there should be no major problems, but I would recommend just using Kotlin as it's better.

Comment: Why don't you just try to do it? Yes, it should work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

From [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html):

> Kotlin is designed with Java interoperability in mind. Existing Java code can be called from Kotlin in a natural way, and Kotlin code can be used from Java rather smoothly as well. ...Pretty much all Java code can be used without any issues...

Anroid Developers website also provides a complete documentation on Kotlin-Java interop:

- [Java (for Kotlin consumption)](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop#java_for_kotlin_consumption)
- [Kotlin (for Java consumption)](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop#kotlin_for_java_consumption)